# Error populating a c# array

Tags: c#

I am trying to do this but getting syntax errors. Is there something I am doing wrong? Do I have to make a specific class to fit each of these objects in every time?

```
var groups = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Conversation' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Business' },
    { id: 27, name: 'Animals' }
];
```

Comment: Looks like javascript to me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not  C#; try:

```
var groups = new [] {
    new { id = 1, name = "Conversation" },
    new { id = 2, name = "Business" },
    new { id = 27, name ="Animals" }
};
```

That said... working with anonymous types is awkward; you *probably* want to declare  a type that has an `Id` and a `Name` and use that instead:

```
var groups = new [] {
    new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "Conversation" },
    new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "Business" },
    new Foo { Id = 27, Name ="Animals" }
};
...
class Foo {
     public int  Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I'd opt for a `struct` over a `class`.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre no; that won't compile, and even if it  did: it doesn't express the  multiplicity correctly. I maintain that the code I've presented  is the  closest to the  javascript version

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for clearing that up, I was going off the fact that C# documentation says this is valid `int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` - I guess that's only for explicit typing?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre correct; the only way of expressing that  in the case of anonymous types is via `var x = new[] { new {...}, new {...}` - it is the `Foo[] x = ` that tells the compiler to expect an array, and you can't use that with anonymous types.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var groups = new object[] { new { id=1, name="Conversation" },
new { id=1, name="Conversation" },
new { id=1, name="Conversation" }
};
```

Comment: adding `object` means you throw away the type information re the anonymous type; that's a bad idea